# Why is "None" value In clientIDArray?

Tags: python, openpyxl

openPyxl places a None value if cell is blank but I would think my logic prevents the None value from being populated into array.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

from openpyxl import load_workbook


wb = load_workbook("sample.xlsx")

sheetArray = []

for sheetName in wb.sheetnames:
    sheetArray.append(sheetName)
    # print(sheetName)

sheet_1 = wb[sheetArray[0]]

lastRow = sheet_1.max_row

# print(lastRow)

clientIDArray = []

for row in sheet_1.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=lastRow, min_col=1, max_col=1):
    if [row[0].value] != "None":
        clientIDArray.append(row[0].value)

for id in clientIDArray:
    print(id)

wb.close()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `if [row[0].value] != "None":` is comparing a list whose single element is `row[0].value`. That list can never be equal to `None` or `"None"` or anything else but a list. You probably wanted to just compare `row[0].value`.

Second, the values you're trying to filter out are presumably `None` values, not string values whose characters are `"None"`.

Third, if the last one is right, you almost always want to use `is`, not `==`, to compare with `None`.

So:

```
if row[0].value is not None:
```

Comment: @abamert I changed the code to what you suggested and None is still showing up in array.

Comment: @GaryDorman Try adding `print(repr(row[0].value))` right before the `if`, and show us the output in an edit to the question.

Comment: I got it work with your original suggestion. I didn't make the right change initially. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should change the code like this. `None` is built-in object.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/constants.html#None

```
if row[0].value is not None:
```

Comment: You need to change `[row[0].value]` to `row[0].value`. have you changed it?

Comment: Ah okay. I thought i made the right change but my eyes failed me. I made the proper change and it works now. Thank you!

Comment: Congratulation :)

Answer (score 0):

Where you have put

```
if [row[0].value] != "None":
    clientIDArray.append(row[0].value)
```

the `[row[0].value]` is creating a list with the `row[0].value` as its item. This means that as a list, it will never be `None`, hence your if statement always executes, and the `None` value gets put into the array.

If `row[0].value` is `None` then your if statement becomes

```
if [None] != "None":
```

and a list can never be `None`.

Also, you should use `None` over `"None"`